# XSL template precedence

Tags: xslt, operator-precedence

I have 2 Templates

```
<template match="vehicle_details[preceding-sibling::vehicle_type = '4x4']/*">
    ...
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="vehicle_details[descendant::color = 'red']/*" >
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

My question is: which template will take precedence on transformation. And can someone give me an overview/resources about XSL template precedence?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The full resolution process is described in [section 5.5 of the XSLT spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#conflict).

In general, the following rules apply in order (e.g. a template eliminated from consideration due to lower import precedence is eliminated permanently, regardless of its priority):

1. Imported templates have lower precedence than templates in the primary stylesheet
2. Templates with a higher value in their `priority` attribute have higher precedence
3. Templates without a `priority` attribute are assigned a default priority. Templates with more specific patterns take precedence.
4. It's an error if the previous three steps leave more than one template in consideration, but XSLT processors can recover by defaulting to the last one in the file.

In your specific case both templates have the same priority, so #4 above applies. To demonstrate:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match=
             "vehicle_details[preceding-sibling::vehicle_type = '4x4']/*">
        template1
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="vehicle_details[descendant::color = 'red']/*">
        template2
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input (both templates match):

```
<root>
    <vehicle_type>4x4</vehicle_type>
    <vehicle_details>
        <color>red</color>
    </vehicle_details>
</root>
```

Output:

```
template2
```

But if we swap the order of the templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="vehicle_details[descendant::color = 'red']/*">
        template2
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match=
             "vehicle_details[preceding-sibling::vehicle_type = '4x4']/*">
        template1
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the output is:

```
template1
```

Comment: A good explanation must make it absolutely clear that import precedence and `priority` are two different things and regardless how high priority a template in an imported stylesheet has, its precedence is lower than the precedence of any template in the importing stylesheet.

Comment: @Dimitre - I intended the rules to be read sequentially. Maybe that wasn't clear. I've added an additional bit of explanation.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. **Observation: It's bad practice to rely on error recovery mechanism.**

Comment: Important for priority values (!): the maximum "default priority" is 0.5, so you can use 1, 2, etc.

Comment: As for your 4. above: is it possible to ask [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) to be `--verbose` about such conflicts and the conflict candidates? That would be a helpful debug feature.